# Как подружить CDEK Shipping Official и Simple

Tags: opencart3.x, cdek

Я являюсь разработчиком сайта cabincrewaccessories.ru. В данный момент на сайте установлен модуль CDEK Shipping Official, а так же модуль упрощенного заказа(Simple) - для исключения из заказа "Шага 2: Платежная Информация", но без него не работает модуль: при клике на выбрать ПВЗ ничего не происходит, а в консоли появляется ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: window.CDEKWidget is not a constructor. Подскажите, как подружить эти два модули и достичь необходимого результата.

Пыталась найти нативный код, в котором можно исправить получение адреса из формы на автоматическое определение города, по типу как в виджете сдэка, но не смогла разобраться. Может кто сталкивался с такой задачей?

Comment: Может обратиться в службу поддержки компании cdek?